# Are there classical examples of the imperative patere?

Tags: classical-latin, passage-request, imperative, deponent-verbs

I wanted to see how the imperative *patĕre* of *pati* is used and I made [a corpus search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23patere%23).
However, most of the results seem to be polluted with the infinitive *patēre*, and I'm having hard time finding examples of the imperative.

Can you list a couple of passages with the imperative *pati* (the more, the better) so I could get a better sense of how it is used?
I asked [a separate question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5523/79) about corpus searches with specific vowel lengths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to distinguish *patere* from *patēre* in a corpus search, so I think you have three choices:

1. Look through the results.
2. Come up with another search that captures what you are looking for.
3. Try to think of a contextual word that would remove (most) false positives.

As it happens, all three methods worked for me!

1. The second result in your link is perfectly good, though it comes from Plautus:

   > Pyrg. Quid ego? híc astabo tántisper cum hac fórma et factis frústra?
   >   Pal. **Patere** átque asta, tibi ego hánc do operam. (Plautus, *Miles Gloriosus* 1021-22)

   If you are insistent on something classical, you can filter it with something like "[Cic]". The third page had the following result:

   > Nunc te obiurgari **patere**, si iure. (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 4.16.9)
2. If you are just looking for an imperative...why not search for *patimini*? Though you still have some false positives for the indicative, it's not too difficult to sort through:

   > Tum Scipio: **Patimini** me, quoniam tertium diem iam feriati sumus... (Cicero, *De Republica* 6.8)
3. Why not search for an obvious combination, such as ["patere me"](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23patere+me%23) (="allow me")? The linked page includes 4 results, all of which are imperative and 3 of which are classical.

Comment: Many thanks! These are all great suggestions. I will do some research on them tonight.

Comment: [This answer has been nominated as one of the best answers of the second half of 2017.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/79)