# Does any text corpus allow quantity-sensitive searches?

Tags: vowel-quantity, soft-question, text-corpus

Is there a text corpus, preferably of classical Latin, in which one can or even must search with specific vowel quantities?
This came up [when I wanted to search for *patĕre* but not *patēre*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5521/79) and had difficulties.
The specific need was satisfied, but the general question remains:
Can I disambiguate different vowel quantities in a corpus search?

Comment: This is a frustrating problem now that you bring it up!